# How to return a view from a different action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view called `DetailsLane` and another `AddItem`. When the `DetailsLane` is rendered, it returns a model class with properties. The `AddItem` action is inside of the same controller, but when I finish whatever I had to do inside of this action, I can't re-render the `DetailsLane` to update the view.

The view is called first time: it works!

```
public ActionResult DetailsLane(int? id, int? IdInstance)
{
    return View(get(IdInstance, id));
}

public ActionResult AddLine(FormCollection collection)
{
      // I did my stuff in here, and I want to return the initial View or,
      // validate something from the collection.
      return DetailsLane(val, val);     // doesn't work!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `RedirectToAction` and you can pass arguments as shown here

```
public ActionResult AddLine(FormCollection collection)
{
  // I did my stuff in here, and I want to return the initial View or,
  // validate something from the collection.
  return RedirectToAction("DetailsLane", new { id = val1, IdInstance = val2 });
}
```

note that `id` and `IdInstance` match the parameter names in your `DetailsLane` action method.